# "adjusting glasses"?

Tags: phrases, expressions

What is the idiomatic way to describe an action by which a person puts their eyeglasses back if they are a bit off down the nose (and does that often as a habitual unconscious move)?

(I mean something along the lines of Russian "поправлять очки", if that helps).

Comment: Google translates *поправлять очки* as "correct points". Is that really the literal translation?

Comment: @AndrewLeach it is a correct translation of a completely different meaning ("adjusting points"). "Очки" may stand for "points", indeed, just as "glass" is a few different things.

Comment: @EarlGray, correct me if I'm wrong, but очки also means glasses, so the phrase implies someone who is constantly fixing his glasses.

Comment: "fixing someone's glasses" - is this wording good? If so, it answers my question.

Comment: @EarlGray No.  I would assume "fixing someone's glasses" means repairing them, in certain contexts.

Comment: @James Just as I thought, but I did not know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called **pushing your glasses up** or **pushing your glasses back**:

> Instead of constantly **pushing your glasses back onto your face** like a
>   stereotypical 90s movie nerd, weblog Tested recommends wrapping the
>   ends in a bit of heat shrink to keep them from slipping.

(http://lifehacker.com/5899908/add-some-heat-shrink-to-your-glasses-to-stop-them-from-slipping-down-your-face)

I think **adjusting your glasses** typically refers to a situation when the glasses slide down, and you need to, for example, adjust the plastic frames in hot water to make them work again.

Comment: Yes, I had the impression that "adjusting your glasses" is too heavyweight to describe the situation.

Comment: "He adjusted his glasses" is possible (just like "He adjusted his tie"), and in a certain context would convey the same idea. But a sentence like "My glasses keep sliding off and I need to constantly adjust them" is sort of ambiguous. Googling and personal experience suggests most people would take it to mean you need to mechanically adjust the glasses' ends. *Pushing up* is clear and unambiguous.

Comment: No problem, *vsegda pozhaluysta* :)

Comment: If it was trousers which were falling down, one would say *he hitched up his trousers*. But as glasses are worn higher up the body, *hitch* doesn't unfortunately work.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [fair amount of fiction](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pushed+his+glasses+up+his+nose%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) that uses the phrase

> he pushed his glasses up his nose

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps fidgeting? Or compulsively fidgeting?

As in, "The old man was sweating profusely in the room. He did not want to be there. He fidgeted with his glasses as they slid down his nose, but for some reason he gave the impression that even if they weren't slipping off his face, he wouldn't have been able to leave them alone."

Comment: It's rather close, but "поправлять" is neither nervous nor emotional, it is a habitual unconscious move.

Comment: Thanks for "fidgeting", by the way, I did not know this word.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever have a need for something shorter than the accepted phrase, I call what I do unconsciously with/to my glasses throughout the day as “[straightening](https://books.google.com/books?id=BnxiPgcwzL0C&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=%22straightened+her+glasses%22&source=bl&ots=dDVkt8SNVb&sig=4mCYAOKfjx4TG0KUVCS7Og9p9E8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAmoVChMI9ObqsOnZyAIVgrYeCh3gewSA#v=onepage&q=%22straightened%20her%20glasses%22&f=false)” them :

“I probably [unconsciously] straighten my glasses at least every fifteen minutes” (usually just before lighting a cigarette).

To the extent that “straightening” would still seem too much like you’re talking about a visit to the local optician, maybe “[reposition/ed](https://books.google.com/books?id=oTT42NjyNAcC&pg=PA144&dq=%22unconsciously+repositioned+his+glasses%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAGoVChMIm8rdiefZyAIVCXYeCh2MBQRl#v=onepage&q=%22unconsciously%20repositioned%20his%20glasses%22&f=false)” would be less ambiguous:

“She unconsciously repositions her glasses constantly throughout the day whether they need it or not.”

(examples of usages other than the ones concocted by me above are found at the above links: ‘Rafe Palladin: Man Of Secrets’ for “straightened” and ‘Definition Murder: A Meg Mccafferty Mystery’ for “repositioned”; both via Google books)

> **[Reposition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/reposition)**
>   … verb [with object] 1Place in a different position; adjust or alter
>   the position of: ‘try repositioning the thermostat in another room’
>
> **[Straighten](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/straighten)**
>   … verb 1Make or become straight: [with object]: she helped him
>   straighten his tie

(definitions from Oxford Dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there isn't a direct translation, I think I would say 'he was habitually adjusting his glasses'

Answer (score 0):

Consider, **shoving one's glasses back up one's nose**.

> shove: to push quickly, forcefully, or roughly: shoved the chair
>   against the wall [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English
>   Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shove)
>
> *The woman stood there one arm braced on her hip, and the old man kept shoving his glasses back up his nose.* [The Birds in Langfoot's
>   Belfry](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=0o-2aI5qAJcC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=%22shoving+his+glasses+back+up%22&source=bl&ots=yiymekdFKT&sig=_nSzYPYXRTxUThKScZTYsWJVmkE&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBGoVChMI0LXdicDZyAIVimwaCh2-LwGN#v=onepage&q=%22shoving%20his%20glasses%20back%20up%22&f=false)